# i want to upload video on youtube in php using api but i have error "The session state did not match" in using client library

Tags: php, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I want to let users to upload videos to YouTube using php. It means if some one  that they visit my site, click on the button "Upload video", choose the file and it uploads to YouTube in my channel . The users don't sign in their own accounts.